# create objects of different models in single ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use single ModelForm to create objects of different models?

I'm trying something like this, but "...name 'model' is not defined..." :

```
urls.py
path('<modelname>/create', views.object_create, name='object-create')

views.py
def object_create(request, modelname):

    if request.method != 'POST':
            form = ObjectForm(modelname)
            return render (request, 'product/form.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('product:feature-list'))

        return render (request, 'product/form.html', {'form':form})

forms.py
class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

        def __init__(self, modelname, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.model =  apps.get_model('product', modelname)

        class Meta:
            model = model
```

Comment: The problem was solved with modelform_factory(). But what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Your `Meta` class is evaluated before you ever create an instance of your class (as the server starts up, I believe), so `model` actually is undefined at that time. I think you wanted to reference `self.model`, but `ObjectForm.Meta` has a different `self` than `ObjectForm`, and, in fact, has no `self`at all in the class scope.

Comment: If you mean like `ModelFoo` and `ModelBar`, the answer is no.